# Can't return children as shouldRender doesn't update

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useLocalState("", "user");
  const [isAuthorized, setIsAuthorized] = useState(false);
  const [privilege, setPrivilege] = useState(null);
  const [shouldRender, setShouldRender] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function checkPriv() {
      if (user.hasOwnProperty("email")) {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/check-authorization", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ email: user.email }),
        });

        const data = await response.json();
        console.log("data: ", data, "is authorized: ", data.isAuthorized, "is priv: ", data.privilege);
        setIsAuthorized(data.isAuthorized);
        setPrivilege(data.privilege);
        console.log("got data back");
        console.log(privilege);

        if (data.isAuthorized && data.privilege === "manager") {
          console.log("user found");
          setShouldRender(true);
        } else {
          console.log("priv failed");
          setShouldRender(false);
        }
      }
    }
    checkPriv();
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("isAuthorized: ", isAuthorized);
    console.log("privilege: ", privilege);

    if (isAuthorized && privilege === "manager") {
      console.log("user found");
      setShouldRender(true);
    } else {
      console.log("priv failed");
      setShouldRender(false);
    }
  }, []);
  const renderedComponent = useMemo(()=>{
    console.log("rednsdsdk")
  if (shouldRender) {
    return children;
  } else {
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  }
},[]);
return renderedComponent;
};
export default PrivateRoute;
```

I don't understand why I can't use the updated shouldRender value here. I know useStates don't update unless in useEffect but does the updates get overwritten when outside of an useEffect? Im sorry if its a dumb question, still new to react.

I tried using it without any sort of states too but it still didn't work

Comment: To re-render something related to a state, you must add the state in the brackets at the end of the useEffect, in your case `useEffect( () => { }, [shouldRender] )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let me help you with a lot of clean ups and rewrites

```js
const PrivateRoute = React.memo(({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useLocalState("", "user");
  const [isAuthorized, setIsAuthorized] = useState(false);
  const [privilege, setPrivilege] = useState(null);
  const [shouldRender, setShouldRender] = useState(false);

  const make_request = React.useCallback(async () => {
      return await fetch("http://localhost:3001/check-authorization", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ email: user.email }),
        })
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(data => data);
}, [user])

  const checkPriv = React.useCallback(async () => {
      if (user.hasOwnProperty("email")) {
        const data = await make_request()


        console.log("data: ", data, "is authorized: ", data.isAuthorized, "is priv: ", data.privilege);
        setIsAuthorized(data.isAuthorized);
        setPrivilege(data.privilege);
        console.log("got data back");
        console.log(privilege);

        if (data.isAuthorized && data.privilege === "manager") {
          console.log("user found");
          // do something here if success
          setShouldRender(true);
        } else {
          console.log("priv failed");
          // do something here if it failed
          setShouldRender(false); 

         // since you want to navigate to "/" if the check is false, you can simply do it here
         document.location.assign('/')
        }
      }
    }, [user])

  useEffect(() => {
    checkPriv();
  }, []);
  
  
    return shouldRender ? children : '';
});


export default PrivateRoute;
```

use shouldRender to check if the user is authorized or not before displaying the content, `useCallback` is a React hook for creating memoised callback function in react, so to prevent re-rendering issues, you can learn more about React hooks online, I put the request outside of the function for resusability, and I also memoised the component instead of the useMemo function you used in the code, these are best practices in React JS for creating React apps with best user experience

and you said useState doesn't update except in useEffect, no, it can be updated anywhere within the component, to use a state inside a function or hook it is a must to pass the state variable to the hook as a dependency else it will not be updated when you use the state inside the function or hook, for explanation

`exampleState` is a state that you want to use inside a function, best way to use it is to wrap the function inside a useCallback hook the pass the state as a dependency to it like so:

```js
const exampleFn = React.useCallback(() => {
 // then when you call this function exampleState's value will be an updated value
}, [exampleState])
```

let me know if it helps

Comment: Thank you so much, This works but there's only one problem. I think rn the children gets returned regardless. So what happens is the privateRoute renders the privateRoute for a second and then travels back to the home page. Is there a way to not make either the children render or just the homepage?

Comment: okay, I will update my answer